# asp.net mvc 4 display many images

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, image, compression, base64

I am writing an application to display many pictures (50-60).
pls, advise to me how best to implement it.
50-60 queries do not very well for one .
At first I did following method: 1. convert pictures to base64; 2. return collection via Json (50-60 lines), but it takes a lot of space. I'm try compressed base64 but not effective

Comment: Where are you going to be pulling images from DB of folder/files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be worth taking a look at the [asp.net sprite and image optimization framework](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/65787).

Hanselman did a nice blog on it [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek1ASPNETSpriteAndImageOptimization.aspx).

It is also available on nuget as [AspNetSprites-MvcAndRazorHelper](http://nuget.org/packages/AspNetSprites-MvcAndRazorHelper)

Also be aware that not all browsers support the [base64 image method](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for a gallery type site I built recently.

I took a collection of file names and programmatically built an XML file on top of my image files library.

```
.
.
.

  <image>
    <filename>/path/thumbnail-blah.jpg</filename>
    <targetimage>/path/blah.jpg</targetimage>
    <description>This is my file description</description>
  </image>
.
.
```

So now I have an XML file with a bunch of nods pointing to different files that I can easily Query with LINQ and quickly get access to any file or files. Can simply pull one file name or all of them, get nod values like  for example (above) and assign it to a  tag on a web page.

Whether this is a good decision to implement in your case will depend on how and how often your images are or removed added to the site.

I integrated logic into my image upload control to automatically upload the XML file(s) as images get uploaded/deleted.